# Authentication Failed on Blueman

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I just bought a QC35 headphone, I'm trying to pair it with blueman. It seems like the device is detected, but when I try to pair it, I get the "Authentication failed" error.

I installed everything bluetooth-related, and made sure my QC35 was in pairing mode, still, can't get it to pair.

Anyone encountered this issue ?

Comment: I also have this issue. No luck yet.

Comment: I've filed a bug upstream: https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/589